# Eclipse's add new package option disappeared

Tags: eclipse

Within my project, i want to add a new package, but realized that option is disappeared. instead if i go to File, i saw "JPA Project", "Enterprise Application Project", "Dynamic Web Project" etc. Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options you see under "File -> New" depend on the Eclipse perspective currently open. You are probably looking at the "Java EE" perspective, and you may be more familiar with the standard Java perspective, which you can open from Window -> Open Perspective -> Java.

You can also create a package from the Java EE perspective by going under: File -> New -> Other... -> Package.

Comment: Thanks a lot, David! According to your suggestion, I found creating package option after switching perspective.